# R: stm() package Prevalence regression failing to converge within iteration limit

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I'm trying to estimate a manyTopics stm model but I get this error:

> Error in vb.variational.reg(Y = lambda[, i], X = covar, Xcorr = Xcorr, :
>   Prevalence regression failing to converge within iteration limit. May want to try gamma.prior='L1'. You >can change max iterations using control. See stm documentation

My code:

```r
temp <- textProcessor(documents=sample$policies,
                      metadata=sample,
                      lowercase=FALSE, 
                      removestopwords=FALSE, 
                      removenumbers=FALSE, 
                      removepunctuation=FALSE, 
                      stem=FALSE,
                      sparselevel=.90)
meta  <- temp$meta
vocab <- temp$vocab
docs  <- temp$documents
out   <- prepDocuments(docs, vocab, meta)
docs  <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
length(vocab)
meta  <- out$meta

storage <- manyTopics(docs, 
                      vocab, 
                      K=c(12),
                      prevalence=~Organization+discuss,
                      max.em.its=500, 
                      data=meta, 
                      runs=50)
```

I only have 135 observations. Could someone please explain what the exact problem is and how could solve it.

Comment: Please share some example data.

Comment: I added a data sample

Comment: I think I fixed it myself already. I was dumb enough to use the actual level of analysis as the prevalence variable. The data is already on the level of organizations, so it doesn't make much sense to put that under prevalence. I still have a lot to learn about stm.